# Use object property as shard key component

Tags: mongodb, key, sharding

I have a sharded database cluster set up and ready to go.

I am at the step to choose the shard key, and I would like to use several fields including nested ones.

For example, I stock documents of this shape :

```
{
    id: 0,
    author: {
        id: 0,
        followers: 0
    }
}
```

And I would like to use the id and the author.id fields to compose my shard key.

I tried with both these syntaxes:

```
sh.shardCollection("test.sample", { "id" : 1, "author" : { "id" : 1 } })
sh.shardCollection("test.sample", { "id" : 1, "author.id" : 1 })
```

But none actually works.

Is this possible to use a nested field as component of a shard key?
If yes how could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

Actually the right syntax is (like for creating an index):

```
sh.shardCollection("test.sample", { "id" : 1, "author.id" : 1 })
```

My problem came from the data I tried to insert in the database.